# Error when trying to communicate in Python

Tags: python-3.x, communication

I want two scripts to communicate in python. I want them to know if the others have failed.

Doing what you see in the picture I have some questions. When I run rob2.py I automatically run rob1.py, why is this?

**rob1.py**

```
import simpy
import time
from rob2 import brok2

class Moving:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        """What does self.prov do?"""
        self.prov = env.process(self.work())
        self.broken = False
        if self.broken == False:
            global brok1
            brok1 = 0
        else:
            brok1 = 0
        #print(brok1)
    def work(self):
        while True:
            yield env.timeout(20)


if brok2 == 1:
    print("Robot 2 is not broken")
else:
    print("Robot 2 is broken")
env= simpy.Environment()
moving = Moving(env)
env.run(until = 60)
```

**rob2.py**

```
import simpy
import time
from rob1 import brok1

class Placing:

    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        """What does self.prov do?"""
        self.prov = env.process(self.work())
        self.broken = False
        if self.broken == False:
            global brok2
            brok2=1
        else:
            brok2 = 0

    def work(self):
        while True:
            yield env.timeout(20)

time.sleep(5)
if brok1 == 1:
    print("Robot 1 is not broken")
else:
    print("Robot 1 is broken")
env= simpy.Environment()
placing = Placing(env)
env.run(until = 60)
```

And what have I done wrong when I get this message trying to run the scripts?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rob2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rob1 import brok1
  File "/Users/erik/Python/python/rob1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rob2 import brok2
  File "/Users/erik/Python/python/rob2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from rob1 import brok1
ImportError: cannot import name 'brok1'
```

I came across some posts about zeroMQ, is that the way to go here?

Comment: Hi Erik and welcome to SO! I strongly suggest you embed your code in the question instead of proving a link to a snapshot image, the same goes for the ouput. Helps readability a lot! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will make the changes!

Comment: Is the problem solved with multithreading, read something about that solving problems running multiple tasks at the same time. correct?

Answer (score 0):

The `ImportError` exception is thrown because Python detects a circular import loop: in one of your files you import the other one, which itself imports the first one, which import the second one and so on.

You will need to reorganize your code to avoid that. 
Most (all?) programming languages will not like a circular import one way or another.

Comment: Any idea how I can reorganize the code to make it work?